# How do i make pytesteract more accurate

Tags: python-3.x

when I use `pytesseract` it messes up with quotations and just random words making it into `ASCII`.

```
text1 = image_to_string(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(688, 235, 1230, 413))).lower().encode("utf-8")
```

When this messes up and thinks something is an `ASCII` character is messes up my program. Is there a way to turn off `ascii` reading?

**ERROR**

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 15: ordinal not in range(128)
```